# How to detect scroll position in Angular Material Autocomplete component

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm using Autocomplete component from `"@angular/material": "^8.2.3"`. I want to make an API call when the scroll position reaches 70% from the top. I tried with the `@ViewChild()` approach, but couldn't detect the scroll event.

I find a constant in [MatAutocomplete API](https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/api) named `MAT_AUTOCOMPLETE_SCROLL_STRATEGY`. But could not find a way to use it.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of mat autocomplete scrollable [Stackblitz Example here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-autocomplete-scrollable?file=app%2Foptions-scroll.directive.ts)